# Option multiplicity with docopt

Tags: python, command-line, argparse, docopt

I would like to using `docopt` for parsing a command line that can receive **the same** option multiple times. Could somebody explain me how to do it?

A test example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Test program.

Usage:
    test.py -v

Options:
    -v  Flag that should be counted
"""

import docopt
print docopt.docopt(__doc__)
```

If I run this with `test.py -v`, I get:

```
{'-v': True}
```

Where as if I run this with `test.py -vv`, it displays the usage message (indicating the command line is not valid).

I'd like to tweak the option documentation so that `docopt` returns me:

```
{'-v': 1}
```

When only 1 `-v` was passed and:

```
{'-v': 3}
```

If, say, the user passed `-vvv`. This is pretty much the same functionality [the `count` action in argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging the docopt (closed) issue list, [I have found that the right way to represent this](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/38) would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Test program.

Usage:
    test.py (-v ...)

Options:
    -v  Flag that should be counted
"""

import docopt
print docopt.docopt(__doc__)
```

That is, one must use the symbol "`...`" to signify that an option may appear multiple times. In this case, the option will be correctly counted. If the above program is called with `test.py -vvv`, it will correctly print:

`{'-v': 3}`

The symbol "`...`" can also be used with arguments and options that take arguments pretty much the same way, just hit the link above for an example of that.

Comment: And this can be extended to passing a list as an argument

Comment: @KaushikGhose Can a list be passed like this: `--input-files a.csv b.csv --output-files c.csv d.csv'? What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat It would be more like:  `--input-files a.csv --input-files b.csv --output-files c.csv --output-files d.csv`

Comment: Thanks. That means globbing is not possible then (even click does not allow for variable length options that way...)

Answer (score 2):

*(This is just a comment to the above, but would get awkward as a comment.)*

And this can be extended to passing a list as an argument:

```
"""
Usage:
program (--opt=OPT ...)

Options:
  --opt=OPT    An option that can be specified multiple times to form a list
"""

import docopt

print docopt.docopt(__doc__)
```

And we run this as

```
python test.py --opt=first_option
{'--opt': ['first_option']}

python test.py --opt=first_option --opt="second in line"
{'--opt': ['first_option', 'second in line']}
```

And so on.